# Pandas how to add column to each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add after each readed row, a column. Basically I want to add informations on every row I read through my loop. My actual dataset called `df` is like this `'label','text'` and I want to finish with `'label','text','prediction'`

For that I want to add a column on each row when I read it like this :

```
 df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file, encoding='utf-8')
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                row['prediction'] = 1
                print((row['label'], row['text'],row['prediction']), file=sys.stderr)
```

but something is wrong because nothing is printed as prediction, I only get the label and the text

Comment: Just do `df["prediction"] = 1` and you will have it on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update a row by iterating like this, regarding [`DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

> You should **never modify** something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns **a copy and not a view**, and writing to it will have no effect.

---

Add the column directly to the whole `df`

```
df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file, encoding='utf-8')
df['prediction'] = 1
```

Comment: and then in my loop I can modify the value of the row ?

Comment: Sure just need to wait 2 minutes to do that